# How to compile and build python library such as wxPython, pymesh, getfem using CMake, mingw and msys and build it for release and debug

Tags: python, cmake, wxpython, mingw, python-3.6

I want to compile and build python libraries such as wxPython, PyMesh, GetFEM for python 3.6 using CMake, MinGW and MSYS and build it for release and debug. I build an application which has a command line type features and I want to access build files directly from the command line.